# SMTP to SMTP protocol

Tags: node.js, smtp

I am trying to write a fake SMTP server in nodejs, I just need use it to send notify email, but not receive email.

I have taken a look at [node-smtp](https://github.com/ralphholzmann/node-smtp), but it just implements the protocol from client to SMTP server, it does not implement how to send mail from a SMTP server to another SMTP server.

If I know how one SMTP server send mail to another SMTP server, I think I can send mail without a SMTP server.

Comment: "Send mail without a SMTP server"?  Where would you send it if not a server?  Mail clients don't receive with SMTP (e.g., POP3, IMAP, MAPI) so you can't send it directly to clients.  They use a pull model anyway, clients fetch mail from servers, you need to send the mail to a server.

Answer (score 1):

> but it just implements the protocol from client to SMTP server, it does not implement how to send mail from a SMTP server to another SMTP server.

An SMTP server that can send mail also acts as an SMTP client. Not that you're trying to write an SMTP server anyway:

> I just need use it to send notify email, but not receive email.

aka

> I just need to write an SMTP client

Comment: I think I got it. but if I talk to any SMTP server, server request authenticate for my user, but if SMTP server act as an SMTP client, it wont tell the receiver SMTP server any login information. How to explain it?

Comment: guilin it depends on server configuration, nowdays they asks for authentication to prevent using them as relay servers for spam.. but when you are talking to server which is responsible to hold mails in domain to which you want to send message then it will not ask for any credentials

Comment: You can determine the authoritative SMTP server using DNS and querying for MX records.

Comment: I don't get it. I just successfully send a mail from localhost to a SMTP server, cheat as a gmail account. Does the SMTP server should check whether the mail is send from correct source.

Answer (score 0):

Well in short it works this way: server-sender reads domain of recipient and is checking DNS for MX record for that domain (you can read it like - "hey DNS tell me please which server holds mails for that domain). Then it connects to remote SMTP and gives the messaage.
The dialogue could look like this:

```
client: HELLO server
server: 250 hello client, nice to meet you
client: MAIL FROM: tmg
server: 250 ok
client: RCPT TO: guilin
server: 250 ok
client: data
server: 354 Enter message, ending with "." on a line by itself
client: From: tmg
client: To: guilin
client: Subject: just a mail
client:
client: message body
client: .
server: 250 ok
client: quit
server: good bye
```

Comment: thank you for detail talk. I saw HELO MAIL RCPT DATA . QUIT, but I don't see any thing From: To: Subject: could you give me more information about this?

Comment: These are not commands, these are headers then is empty line and message body and dot. If you don't give headers then server will create ones

Answer (score 0):

Did you look at Marak's node_mailer?

https://github.com/Marak/node_mailer

I have a fork of it, and another one, on my github site, for gmail smtp support

http://github.com/deitch

Answer (score 0):

I use https://github.com/andris9/simplesmtp, it is actually a framework for creating SMTP servers/clients, however it is quite a good fit for testing.

There is also https://github.com/deitch/smtp-tester specially designed for testing, however I haven't used it.